# How to use ID to retrieve record within nested ngFor Loops in Ionic / Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Ionic / Angular app, I am trying to display a list of Conversations between users on the *Conversation_List* page.

Here are the models:

**Conversation Model:**

```js
import { Message } from './message.model';

export class Conversation {
     constructor(
         public id: string,
         public userId: string,
         public mechanicId: string,
         public messages: Message[],
    ) { }
}
```

**Message Model:**

```js
export class Message {
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public text: string,
        public userId: string,
        public timestamp: string
    ) { }
}
```

**User Model:**

```js
export class User{
    constructor(
        public id: string,
        public name: string,
        public userType: string
    ) { }
}
```

Currently, I am able to display the Data stored inside my ***loadedConversations*** variable below.

However, instead of displaying the userId, I'd like to use that ID to search my *loadedUsers*, & display the name associated with that ID.

For example, Conversation C1 has a UserId = abc1. I would like to use this UserId to search my Users, & display their name.

Here is the code in Conversation Service:

```js
private _conversations: Conversation[] = [
    new Conversation(
        'c1',
        'abc1',
        'def2',
         [
             new Message('mess1', 'Test message', 'abc1', '01/01/2020'),
             new Message('mess2', 'Another message', 'def2', '02/01/2020')
         ]
    ),
    new Conversation(
        'c2',
        'xuz1',
        'ghi2',
        [
            new Message('mess1', 'my  message', 'xuz1', '05/03/2020'),
            new Message('mess2', 'more messages', 'ghi2', '08/03/2020')
        ]
    )
];

get conversations() {
    return [...this._conversations];
}
```

And here is Conversation_List TS:

```js
export class ConversationListPage implements OnInit {

      loadedConversations: Conversation[];

      constructor(private conversationsService: ConversationsService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.loadedConversations = this.conversationsService.conversations;
      }

    }
```

Conversation_List HTML:

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let conversation of loadedConversations">
    <ion-label>
        <h2>USER ID: {{ conversation.userId}}</h2>
        <p>MECHANIC ID: {{ conversation.mechanicId }}</p>
        <p>MESSAGES: {{ conversation.messages }}</p>
    </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

Any ideas on what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create and store users first that you can then reference. This is similar to Primary and Foreign Keys in database. Your current code adds the userId as a simple string and does not check whether that userId actually exists.

I suggest you create a user service that holds an array of users:

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService() {

    users: User[];


    constructor() {
        this.users = [
            new User('abc123', 'Peter', 'myUserType');
        ]
    }
}
```

Additionally, that service should provide a method to return a user/username for a provided userId. For example like this:

```js
getUserNameByUserId(userId: string): User {
    return this.users.filter(user => user.userId === userId)[0].name;
}
```

What you do here is check if any user does fullfil the condition of having a userId that is equal to the provided one. Filter can return multiple matches, therefor take the first one. In your example filter should only return a single match, however, as stated, the return type of that method is an array.

Finally, in your component you can call that method and get the username.

First inject the userService:

```js
constructor(protected userService: UserService){}
```

Then in your template call your new method to get the userName.

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let conversation of loadedConversations">
    <ion-label>
        <h2>USER ID: {{ userService.getUserNameByUserId(userId) }}</h2>
        <p>MECHANIC ID: {{ conversation.mechanicId }}</p>
        <p>MESSAGES: {{ conversation.messages }}</p>
    </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

Alternatively, you could map the values inside your conversationArray to have userNames instead of userIds:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadedConversations = this.conversationsService.conversations.map(
        conversation => {
            ...conversation,
            userId: this.userService.getUserNameByUserId(conversation.userId)
        }
    );
}
```

You map each conversation to a new object, that contains the same fields (note the *spread-operator* (the three dots ... )) to copy all fields into the new object) and adjusts the userId by replacing the actual userId with the userName.

This however would violate your logical structure of the conversation object as your userId is now actually a userName. Might only be a temporary workaround ;-)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, your first suggestion worked perfectly. The only change you need to make is update `return this.users.filter(user => user.id = userId)[0].name;` to `return this.users.filter(user => user.id === userId)[0].name;`. If you only use one = sign, it takes the first user in the Users array each time